# load file IN javascript using Flask

Tags: python, flask, three.js

I am trying to load a 3d file into three.js with Flask

I've tryied in my .html

```
<script> 
    var tridi = '{{ url_for('static', filename = 'mesh.dae') }}'    
</script>
```

then load my .js file

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
                loader.load( tridi, function ( collada ) {
                    elf = collada.scene;
                } );
```

but it doesn't seems to work :/

I've also tryied

```
<script> 
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
                    loader.load( "{{ url_for('static', filename='mesh.dae') }}", function ( collada ) {
                        elf = collada.scene;
                    } );
var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager( function() {
                            scene.add( elf );
                    } );
</script>
```

any help pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Loader was the problem, the request was correct,
I've try all the loaders from Three.js, only

```
THREE.ObjectLoader()
```

finnaly worked is used https://threejs.org/editor/ to make a scene.json file

Answer (score 0):

why don't u just load the script ? and name your file .js

`var loader` will be accessible in the main scope.

```
<script src="mesh.js"></script>
```